# How to get all records from one table between dates of column in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using sql server, I have a queues table has a column called process_date, and a users table has a column called process_date, there is no relation between the two tables. I want to get all users that has been processed with one queue depending on process_date (I have the queue_id and I want to return all users that have been processed with that queue) 
How can I write a query to do so?

update: the process_date is date time so it's not a match for the queue and the users, that's why I needed to get the process date for the previous queue and then the current queue and then get the users that were processed in that date range

Comment: Can you show some sample rows in the tables? And your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process_date field is date time so it won't be a match that's why I'm not joining, What I did is selecting the previous process_date from the queue, and the process_date for the current queue, and then selecting the users with process_date between these two dates

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT
    *
    FROM Users
        WHERE EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 
                1 
                FROM [Queue] 
                    WHERE [Queue].process_date = Users.process_date 
                    AND [Queue].QueueId = 1
        )
```

this will return all users processed for queue_id 1.

**Note**: 
it is not recommended to join tables based on some dates to retrieve the records. so if possible, you should add a queue id to the users' table and create a foreign key constraint with the queue table. then update the queue id for each user because time ca  variation  in milliseconds can also leade to miss match in the above

Answer (score 0):

With so little detail to work with any answer will likewise be "thin on detail" too. e.g.

```
select * from users u 
inner join queue q on u.process_date = q.process_date
```

or if there is some form of delay then perhaps a small time range may be needed: e.g.

```
select * from users u 
inner join queue q on u.process_date between q.process_date and dateadd(minute,1,q.process_date)
```